# How to align multiple field labels in bootstrap and simple form

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

This is how my current form looks like [image: registration form]

As you can see, the labels are not well aligned. I want them to look like this 
[image: aligned picture]

This is my code for the all the inputs

```
    <%= simple_form_for [@company], html: { class: 'form-horizontal' },wrapper: :horizontal_form do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
           <%= f.input :name,  :label => "Name of Company" %>
      </div>
      </div>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: Those are what I'd call REAL screenshots! :-)

Comment: "Well Aligned" isn't very explanative... in your screenshot they are aligned *perfectly* with how `control-label` works.  Is it just that you want `control-label` to align the text to the left of the column instead of the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using bootstrap `form-horizontal` class. To resolve this you have to override the bootstrap css.

Paste below css in your custom css file(Try to use parent class of yours)

```
.parent-class .form-horizontal .control-label {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly. any idea how i can remove the scroll bar on the "what do you do section" (the second section)?    This is my code for that section                                                                                                   
       <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-1 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <%= f.input :description, as: :text, :label => "What do you do" %>
      </div>
    </div>
Thank you

Comment: @HakeemBaba I don't have any idea why is your scrollbar coming....try `textarea{overflow:hidden}`....may be this will help...